# Recursive function to sum numbers inbetween two others

Tags: c, recursion

I want to sum each number inbetween two others (e.g. 1 to 5 would be sum = 9, 2+3+4), but my function always returns 0 and I honestly don't understand why.
Hope you can help me, thanks.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int inbetween_sum (int N1, int N2);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int n1, n2, sum;
    printf("n1:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    printf("n2:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n2);
    sum = inbetween_sum(n1, n2);
    printf("%d", sum);
    return 0;
}

int inbetween_sum (int N1, int N2) {
    int sum1 = 0;
    if (N1 == N2) {
       return sum1;
   }
   sum1 += inbetween_sum (N1+1, N2);
   return sum1;
}
```

Comment: Step through the code in your debugger - you will soon see the bug.

Comment: Your `inbetween_sum` will always yield a result of 0. You should reconstruct the recursive calls on a piece of paper and try to understand what is happening

Comment: I think in every loop you are returning a 0. So, basically you keeping adding up 0, which is 0.

Comment: Thank you, writing it down really helped me understand which mistake I was doing.

Answer (score 3):

Line `sum1 += inbetween_sum (N1+1, N2);` is faulty. All you ever return or add is `0` and never the actual number.

Rewrite your function as:

```
int inbetween_sum (int N1, int N2) {
   int sum1 = 0;
   if (N1 >= N2 - 1) {
       return sum1;
   }
   sum1 += N1 + 1 + inbetween_sum (N1+1, N2);
   return sum1;
}
```

[Live example here](http://ideone.com/eVlHS7)

Comment: you're answer is confusing, why not change it to return N1 + 1 + inbetween_sum (N1+1, N2) - my mistake

Comment: It could be simplified, but it does *not* have the same problem as the original.  It works.

Comment: @MohitJain: no problem - actually it was just a minimal edit so that I could remove my (incorrect) down-vote.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding zeros. You have to add `N1 + 1` to your sum and change stop condition

```
int inbetween_sum (int N1, int N2) {
   int sum1 = 0;
   if (N1 + 1 >= N2) {
      return sum1;
   }
   sum1 += N1 + 1 + inbetween_sum (N1+1, N2);
   return sum1;
}
```

Also initializing sum1 to 0 and then using += is not clear. Your code can be refactored to:

```
int inbetween_sum (int N1, int N2) {
   if (N1 + 1 >= N2) {
      return 0;
   }
   return N1 + 1 + inbetween_sum (N1+1, N2);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I did something like that afterwards and it works fine.